# Whats the point of having a conversion constructor

Tags: c++

After reading about the conversion constructor I came up with the conclusion that it is simply a class constructor that has one parameter. This [page](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr384.htm) explains it a lot however I am still confused with it use. Why is it used ?. So far all I understand is that instead of declaring an instance as such

```
someclass a(12);
```

we could do it like

```
someclass a = 12;
```

Comment: `std::string s = "hello world";` In cases like strings its just more natural to use a conversion constructor. Some features are implmeneted just to make the syntax nicer.

Comment: or `ComplexNumber c = 5;`

Comment: It is also useful if you have a class that acts as a number or value. For example, a high-precision number class, which you can convert from an int.

Comment: It's not just that you can write `someclass a = 12`, but also that (for example) you can pass `12` to a function expecting a `someclass`.

Comment: this may be a bit awkward when you define something like `CSerialPort COM1 = 1;`...

Comment: @V-X valid point, but who would think to write a conversion operator/constructor that converts an integer into an abstraction of a hardware device? Never mind, I probably don't want to know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a conversion constructor

```
SomeClass( int )
```

that means that a function

```
void foo( SomeClass x );
```

could be satisfied by a call of

```
foo( 12 );
```

This might or might not be what you want. The `explicit` keyword is there to avoid such "surprising" conversions.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `explicit` as a way of overcoming the implicit conversion issue.

Comment: Thanks brief and get the meaning across

Answer (score 6):

Its also useful (dangerious) because it can auto convert arguments.

```
 void print(std::string const& str)
 {
     std::cout << str << "\n";
 }


 int main()
 {
     print("Hi"); // That's not a string.
                  // But the compiler spots that std::string has a single 
                  // argument constructor that it can use to convert a 
                  // `char const*` into a std::string with.
 }
```

It is basically there to make the language more simple to write (read).

There is an unfortunate side affect (that they spotted after the fact). That the compiler will convert things you may not want converted automatically. Can't think of one off hand. But they exist. As a result they added the `explicit` keyword for constructors. This prevents the automatic compiler conversion (as you need to explicitly call it).

Thanks `@Mooing Duck`

```
int main()
{
     std::vector<int>  names = 3; // What does this mean?
                                  // This does not compile because of the explicit keyword now.
                                  // But it used to compile and the meaning is not obvious.

     // It gets even worse if you think about a function that takes a vector
     plop(3); // Do you want that to auto converted into an std::vector<int>?
              // Would you not want a compiler error?
}
```

Comment: without the `explicit` keyword, `std::vector<std::string> names = 3;` would have compiled :/

Answer (score 3):

It becomes useful when you want to do **implicit** conversions. for example

```
struct A {
    A(int i) : i(i) {}
    A() : A(0) {}
    int i;
    A operator+(const A& a) {
        return A(i + a.i);
    }
};

void f(A a) {}

int main() {
    A a(1);
    A c = a + 2;  // This wont be possible with out the implicit conversion of 2 to A
    f(3);         // This wont be possible with out the implicit conversion of 3 to A
}
```

Comment: Useful? Check. Potentially dangerous? Double check.

Comment: Yep. No doubt it is dangerous. But it was just an example usage. Me personally wouldn't do it.

Comment: Just like lots of features of C++. Recall that it was designed for professionals, according to Stroustrup. If you're going to abuse a feature then GTFO until you learn to use it properly ;)